# Word interop - hiding styles

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm creating a new Style using Word interop (in Word 2013). It works fine, but I'd like to hide the style from the user. Basically, I'm trying to do the same thing you can do manually when you go to the Styles dialog -> Manage Styles -> Recommended tab and click the Hide button:

[image]

Then, the style description looks like this:

```
Font: (Default) +Headings (Calibri Light), 12 pt, Bold, Space
Before:  6 pt, Style: Hidden, Priority: 100
Based on: Normal
Following style: Normal
```

Is this possible using Word interop? I can change the Priority property of the style (using the `Priority` property of the .NET interface), but I can't seem to add the Hidden property. I tried using the "reserved for internal use" `Hidden` property of the style, but that hides the style completely (even from the Manage Styles window), which I don't want. I also tried playing around with the `UnhideWhenUsed` and `Visibility` properties to no avail.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it's a backwards property, try setting Visibility = true.

Comment: Crazy Microsoft, it works! Thanks a lot, if you want to write this up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to know it worked.  Strange they list that property as "Reserved for internal use."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a backwards property, try setting Visibility = true.